# Separating single grouped WHILE loop results

Tags: php, loops, count, if-statement, while-loop

I asked a question yesterday which was solved and I can now output WHILE loops which 2 results on a line, rather than 1 on a line. This is the code I've got at the moment:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0) {
 $count=0;
 $day = 1;
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<b>";
        if ($day=='1') { echo "Sunday - ";}
        else if ($day=='3') { echo "Monday - "; }
        else if ($day=='5') { echo "Tuesday - "; }
        else if ($day=='7') { echo "Wednesday - "; }
        else if ($day=='9') { echo "Thursday - "; }
        else if ($day=='11') { echo "Friday - "; }
        else if ($day=='13') { echo "Saturday - "; }
        else { echo "";}

        if (($row["open"] == 0) && ($row["close"] == 0)) 
        {
          echo "closed"
        } 
        else
        {
          echo "</b>" . $row["open"] . "-" . $row["close"] . " &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ";
          if ($count % 2 !=0 ){ echo  "<br/><br/>";}
        }
        $count++;
        $day++;
 }
} else {
        echo "Error";
}
```

With this code, when the branch is closed, then it returns the word 'closed' twice, where I need it to appear only once. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you display a copy of the output your getting? Are you getting for example... Sunday - closedclosed or 
Saturday - Closed
Sunday - Closed

Comment: Sunday - 08:00:00-12:30:00      13:30:00-16:30:00     

Monday - 09:00:00-17:00:00      18:00:00-20:00:00     

Tuesday - 09:00:00-17:00:00      18:00:00-20:00:00     

Wednesday - 08:00:00-17:00:00      18:00:00-20:00:00     

Thursday - 09:00:00-17:00:00      18:00:00-20:00:00     

Friday - 08:00:00-17:00:00      18:00:00-21:00:00     

Saturday - closedclosed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just test on modulo the value within `$day` :

in place of :

```
if (($row["open"] == 0) && ($row["close"] == 0)) {
    echo "closed";
}
```

do :

```
if ($row["open"] == 0 && $row["close"] == 0) {
     if ($day % 2 == 1) {
         echo "closed";
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your answer but now I just get the output 'Saturday - closed00:00:00-00:00:00 '.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the most elegant solution but I would probably have a variable `$closed = false`, which gets set to true if the branch is closed. Then just test for `$closed`, if it's false, output "closed".

Comment: Hi, how would I add this into my code? I'm a bit confused as to where everything would go. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for($i=0`;`$i`<`count(row)`;`$i++)
{

}
```